# Undefined Variable for just one function

Tags: php

I have many functions written ,about 10 or so and I use the same format for all,everything seems to work except this one.

```
<?php

function eugpwlogic($x)
{
   if($x <=- "1.9")
   { 
      echo $p=("0.20");
   }
   elseif($x <-"1.8" )
   { 
    echo $p=("0.90");
   }
   return $p;
}

?>
```

I keep getting the same warning notice

```
Notice: Undefined variable: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Testing\final\add.php on line 13
```

Comment: You only define `$p` if it meets one of the criteria in the if statements - add a line at the top intializing it as `$p = 0;`.

Comment: The negated strings make my skin crawl.

Comment: I assume the operator echo has the priority over = ?

Comment: @Virus721 nope. $p just was not defined...

Comment: Also, when including error messages in your question, point out which line they refer to by adding a comment to your code sample. So doesn't number lines in them, and even that wouldn't help if you included an excerpt from your file.

Comment: $p is being defined in the echo. If as you say = has the priority, $p is set when echoing. EDIT : unless neither of the two coditions are true

Comment: Just wanted to point out also that the logical order in this function appears to be reversed... if `$x` is less than or equal to -1.9 then `$x` will *always* already be less than -1.8 meaning the `elseif` condition will never be evaluated. Just a heads-up.

Comment: ... or, what @PhillSparks said. ;)

Comment: Yea i noticed that I changed the logic to include the upper and lower limit

Comment: @LastBreath - PHP only goes down to function level scope - if you declare a variable inside an `if` statement, it will be in-scope in code that follows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
function eugpwlogic($x) {
    $p = 0;
    if ($x <= - 1.9) {
        $p = 0.20;
    } elseif ($x < - 1.8) {
        $p = 0.90;
    }
    return $p;
}

echo eugpwlogic(-2.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function eugpwlogic($x)
{

   $p = null; //define $p !!
   if($x <=- "1.9")
   { 
      echo $p=("0.20");
   }
   elseif ($x <-"1.8" )
   { 
      echo $p=("0.90");
   }

   return $p;

}
```

Comment: I tried this, this time I did not get the notice but the same time I get a blank page.

Comment: You get black result because of `echo $p=("0.90");`

Comment: @user2300435 yea... I am not sure why you are using strings instead of literals.